# Getting record count as -1 in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code in Excel VBA. When I add a watch on RecordSet, it always shows record count as -1. Infact it should show 3. I have checked the Fields in recordset(by adding a watch) and it shows correct field names.

```
Sub ConnectSqlServer()
Dim oConn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim sConnString As String

'Create connection string
sConnString = "Provider=sqloledb; Server=D-SRVR; Database=test;    Trusted_Connection=True; Integrated Security=SSPI;"
'Create the Connection and Recordset objects
Set oConn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

'Open connection and execute
oConn.Open sConnString
Set rs = oConn.Execute("SELECT top 3 * from employee;")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Per MSDN (here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676701(v=vs.85).aspx)

> The cursor type of the Recordset object affects whether the number of records can be determined. The RecordCount property will return -1 for a forward-only cursor; the actual count for a static or keyset cursor; and either -1 or the actual count for a dynamic cursor, depending on the data source.